# Open open source game from inside a "master" application

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android application for a Capstone class at my university with some other students. Our task is to implement open source games that run inside the application when they are selected.

I have done a lot of research looking around after having lots of trouble with it, and I have discovered that there is apparently no way to launch another app as a view in an already running app (you can only launch the outside app which will run on its own).

I saw some suggestions about fragments, but after looking into them, I don't think that fragments is possible either, since I'm trying to run a full application and not just a single class or two.

So am I correct in thinking that there is no way to do this without the already mentioned method of launching the app from inside the already running application, or would fragments be what I need to use to accomplish this?

Comment: Unfortunate for me, but thank you for the quick response.

Comment: this is actually possible. if you have the same shared user id accross apps, you can run an app and have it display in a view of your other app. but that also mean that all the apps are running inside the same process, and just to get the launching right is complicated. Plus it adds some restriction to what the other app can do.